# Difference for application registration in azure ad b2c

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I want to delete azure ad b2c user from azure ad b2c portal, iam using graph api for this purpose. So Manually registered an application in azure ad b2c portal and set permission to application.See below
[image]

and its working fine.Then i tried to  automate the app registration through graph api and set the permission then the app permission is look like below.
[image]
type application is changed to deletegated. And i can't delete  to the user through graph api due to insufficient permission .BELOW IS MY CODE to grant the permission. (POWER SHELL)

STEPS

1. Created an application manually and added some permissions(Application.ReadWrite.All,Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy,Directory.ReadWrite.All,Policy.ReadWrite.TrustFramework,TrustFrameworkKeySet.Read.All,TrustFrameworkKeySet.ReadWrite.All,User.Read.All)
2. Then i write below script using above created application  client id and client secret(for calling graph api).

> ```
> $tenantid ='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
> $appid='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
> $appsecret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'  
> $Uri = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' + $tenantid +'/oauth2/v2.0/token'
>     
> $Form = @{
>         client_id     = $appid
>         scope         = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'
>         client_secret = $appsecret
>         grant_type    = 'client_credentials'
>       }
> $Result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Uri -Method Post -Form $Form -contenttype 'application/json'
> $access_token=$Result.access_token
> $url = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications'
> $headers = @{Authorization = "Bearer $access_token" }
> $method = "Post"
> $json = $bodyjsonstring | ConvertFrom-Json | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10
> $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Body $json -Method $method -Headers $headers -contenttype 'application/json'
> ```

3. Then set a service principle for app

> ```
> $appId = $response.appId
> $urlforappsp = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/serviceprincipals'
>   $dataforsp = '{
>   "appId": "' + $appId + '",
> }'
>   $headers = @{Authorization = "Bearer $access_token" }
>   $method = "Post"
>   $json = $bodyjsonstring | ConvertFrom-Json | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10
>   # Write-Host $json
>   $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $urlforappsp -Body $json -Method $method -Headers $headers -contenttype 'application/json'
>   $responsesp = HTTP_POST_CALL -bearer_token $accesstoken -url $urlforappsp -bodyjsonstring $dataforsp
> ```

4.Then i call the  link

- https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

response is

```html
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#applications/$entity",
    "id": "xxxxxxxxx",
    "deletedDateTime": null,
    "appId": "xxxxxxxx",
    "applicationTemplateId": null,
    "createdDateTime": "2020-12-14T18:23:26Z",
    "displayName": "userapp",
    "description": null,
    "groupMembershipClaims": null,
    "identifierUris": [],
    "isDeviceOnlyAuthSupported": null,
    "isFallbackPublicClient": null,
    "notes": null,
    "optionalClaims": null,
    "publisherDomain": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "signInAudience": "AzureADMyOrg",
    "tags": [],
    "tokenEncryptionKeyId": null,
    "verifiedPublisher": {
        "displayName": null,
        "verifiedPublisherId": null,
        "addedDateTime": null
    },
    "spa": {
        "redirectUris": []
    },
    "defaultRedirectUri": null,
    "addIns": [],
    "api": {
        "acceptMappedClaims": null,
        "knownClientApplications": [],
        "requestedAccessTokenVersion": null,
        "oauth2PermissionScopes": [],
        "preAuthorizedApplications": []
    },
    "appRoles": [],
    "info": {
        "logoUrl": null,
        "marketingUrl": null,
        "privacyStatementUrl": null,
        "supportUrl": null,
        "termsOfServiceUrl": null
    },
    "keyCredentials": [],
    "parentalControlSettings": {
        "countriesBlockedForMinors": [],
        "legalAgeGroupRule": "Allow"
    },
    "passwordCredentials": [],
    "publicClient": {
        "redirectUris": []
    },
    "requiredResourceAccess": [],
    "web": {
        xxxxx
        }
    }
}
```

```
 requiredResourceAccess and approle are empty.then how do i call
```

"/appRoleAssignedTo"

Comment: can you please provide the correlation id and timestamp of error message

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add or Delete an app's API permissions (requiredResourceAccess) via Microsoft Graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57316875/add-or-delete-an-apps-api-permissions-requiredresourceaccess-via-microsoft-gr) Be aware that granting consent is a separate API call.

Comment: @AlexAIT .How do  i change the type to delegation to application through your answer ?.i didn't  see any way

Comment: @SruthiJ-MSFT  Identity Authorization_RequestDenied↵Message: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.↵Inner error:↵ AdditionalData:↵ date: 2020-12-11T05:11:00

Comment: Do you want to use MS graph api to modify your permission type?

Comment: Carl Zhao yes. currently its delegated i want to change it into application

Comment: Is the application created in your azure ad b2c portal?

Comment: yes .i created this application in ad b2c for delete the ad b2c user via ms graph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I  tried to call [Update application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-update?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) graph api to modify the permission type by changing the `requiredResourceAccess` attribute set.  Although it succeeded, and it did change the permission type to application permission in Azure portal, it also changed the permission **name** to **id**. , So I do not recommend you to use this method.

At the same time, I found that you are calling `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/oauth2PermissionGrants` api when automating  permissions. This api is usually used to assign delegation permissions, so if you are assigning application permissions, don’t use it.

The easiest way is to call the [appRoleAssignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-post-approleassignedto?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) graph api, which will directly assign **application permissions** to your application.

You can refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63283450/i-would-like-to-give-admin-consent-to-api-permissions-through-powershell-script/63295541#63295541) to understand the meaning of identifiers.

---

**Update:**

Navigate to your AD App in the `portal` -> `Manifest` -> `requiredResourceAccess`, get the resourceAppId and id, note the `id` down as `appRoleId`.

[image]

Comment: Carl Zhao Thank you for your response. What i am missing is how do i get the role id. Link in your answer is also asking same question. But i did"t  get the role id. Pls help me? check the question i edited and steps added

Comment: @junealex  By the way, this **appRoleId** is fixed, and each id corresponds to a MS graph api permission. You can directly add the application permission in Azure portal, and then find the id corresponding to the permission in the manifest. Or you can call `https ://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals?$filter=appId eq '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'`api, it will return you a permission set.  In addition,  I will explain to you: `"resourceAppId ": "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000"` stands for ms graph api.

Comment: @junealex  If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.) Thanks!

Comment: .i got the requiredResourceAccess in manually created app with added permission through portal. But no requiredResourceAccess in app created thorough scripted app. Still i got confused about app  roleid. For calling  appRoleAssignment  API, app roleid is needed right? .I just created app and its  service principle.THen added delegated permission thorough script .Then i check the  app id.but still requiredResourceAccess is empty

Comment: @junealex  Sorry for my late reply. To call the appRoleAssignment API, appRoleid is required, which is the id in ResourceAccess : https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Nxgo.png